# How to print out dash or dot using fprintf/printf?

Tags: c++, c, text, printf

As of now I'm using below line to print with out dot's

```
fprintf( stdout, "%-40s[%d]", tag, data);
```

I'm expecting the output would be something like following,

```
Number of cards..................................[500]
Fixed prize amount [in whole dollars]............[10]
Is this a high winner prize?.....................[yes]
```

How to print out dash or dot using fprintf/printf?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A faster approach:

If the maximum amount of padding that you'll ever need is known in advance (which is normally the case when you're formatting a fixed-width table like the one you have), you can use a static "padder" string and just grab a chunk out of it. This will be faster than calling `printf` or `cout` in a loop.

```
static const char padder[] = "......................"; // Many chars

size_t title_len = strlen(title);
size_t pad_amount = sizeof(padder) - 1 - title_len;

printf(title); // Output title

if (pad_amount > 0) {
    printf(padder + title_len); // Chop!
}

printf("[%d]", data);
```

You could even do it in one statement, with some leap of faith:

```
printf("%s%s[%d]", title, padder + strlen(title), data);
```

Comment: your last suggestion breaks if `strlen(title) > strlen(padder)`

Comment: @Christoph, hence the proclaimed "leap of faith" :)

Comment: @Ates: interesting concept, this 'faithful programming' of yours ;)

Comment: size_t -> int is required in `if ((int)pad_amount > 0)`

Answer (score 9):

You can easily do this with iostreams instead of printf

```
cout << setw(40) << setfill('.') << left << tag[i] << '[' << data[i] << ']' << endl;
```

Or if you really need to use fprintf (say, you are passed a FILE* to write to)

```
strstream str;
str << setw(40) << setfill('.') << left << tag[i] << '[' << data[i] << ']' << endl;
printf(%s", str.str());
```

Comment: +1 for being easy to read and understand and not breaking under certain (albeit somewhat uncommon situations).

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it in one statement.
You can use sprintf, then substitute dots for spaces yourself, or do 
something like

```
int chars_so_far;
char padder[40+1]= '..........'; //assume this is 40 dots.
printf("%.40s%n",tag,&chars_so_far);
printf("%s[%d]",padder+chars_so_far,data);
```

---

Edit:
  Simplified my example above based on @Ates' padder concept. This way doesn't require any 'leaps of faith', about whether the tag string is too big or too small - it always starts the data in column 41.

Comment: @Ates: it could, but imo not without two calls to `strlen()` if you want to properly check boundaries - therefore, you need to cache this value -> two statements!

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to output the string with the dot or dash padding yourself.

Something like (forgive my C, it's rusty):

```
printAmount(char *txt, int amt) {
    printf("%s",txt);
    for(int xa=strlen(txt); xa<40; xa++) { putc('.'); }
    printf("[%d]",amt);
    printf("\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using a tiny helper function

```
static inline size_t min(size_t a, size_t b)
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}
```

Then, you can do the following:

```
char padder[] = "........................................";
int len = min(strlen(tag), sizeof(padder) - 1);
printf("%.*s%s[%d]", len, tag, padder + len, data);
```

This is essentially what Ates posted, but I actually figured this out on my own ;)

Comment: Change the size_t to int; you must pass an int to the '*' in the printf() family of functions.

Comment: Or make the helper more helpful: printf("%s%s[%d]", title, getPadding(title), data);

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest writing a function that pads a string with X characters and use that to generate the first argument to your `printf` string.  Something like:

```
char s[40];
pad_str(tag, s, 40, '.');
fprintf( stdout, "%-40s[%d]", s, data);
```

Note that the third line of your sample data would need this format:

```
"%-40s[%s]"
```

Comment: This makes the most sense. If you are padding to a fixed amount of characters, you probably want to chop titles that are too long, so it makes sense to use fixed-width arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a better way.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MIN(A,B) ((A)<(B)?(A):(B))
char *dashpad(char *buf, int len, const char *instr) {
    memset(buf, '-', len);
    buf[len] = 0;
    int inlen = strlen(instr);
    memcpy(buf, instr, MIN(len, inlen));
    return buf;
}
main() {
    char buf[40];
    printf("%s\n", dashpad(buf, 40, "Hello world, dash padded "));
}
```

Comment: First filling the entire buffer with the pad character, and then overwriting them seems a bit wasteful though...

Comment: Also, you have a buffer overrun (don't you love C) - s/be:
  buf[len-1]=0;

Comment: And you have a null-erasure bug in you min(), which should also be len-1.

Comment: is it possible to call a function inside printf?

Comment: @Thi: Yes this is legitimate - the function is invoked and it's return passed as a parameter to printf... this is normal coding in any procedural, OOP or functional language.